# Transition an image like the sun rises from an artificial horizon

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm wondering if it is possible to transition an image from an artificial horizon much like you see the sun's disc rise up in the morning? If it is possible, I would like to know how.

If at all possible, I wonder if it could be made to work with the object as a background-image and rise up from 0% to 100%, the bottom of the object resting at the horizon.

The problem is that I want the horizon to be invisible. There cannot be another mask in-front of the image, that would defeat what I'm trying to achieve with the overall presentation.

Comment: To achieve that you could play with left-/right-/top-margin attributes and have the div absolutely positioned. You'll just have to figure out the formula to get the curve correct.

Comment: set a container with overflow hidden, and then set the position of the inner element to move upwards